# How to fix 'yourAPI is not defined'

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, in-app-purchase

I was working on react-native-iap nowadays.
While working, I ran into this problem.
'yourAPI is not defined'

```
import RNIap, {
  purchaseErrorListener,
  purchaseUpdatedListener,
  type ProductPurchase,
  type PurchaseError
} from 'react-native-iap';

class RootComponent extends Component<*> {
  purchaseUpdateSubscription = null
  purchaseErrorSubscription = null

  componentDidMount() {
    this.purchaseUpdateSubscription = purchaseUpdatedListener((purchase: ProductPurchase) => {
      console.log('purchaseUpdatedListener', purchase);
      const receipt = purchase.transactionReceipt;
      if (receipt) {
        yourAPI.deliverOrDownloadFancyInAppPurchase(purchase.transactionReceipt)
        .then((deliveryResult) => {
          if (isSuccess(deliveryResult)) {

            if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
              RNIap.finishTransactionIOS(purchase.transactionId);
            } else if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
              // If consumable (can be purchased again)
              RNIap.consumePurchaseAndroid(purchase.purchaseToken);
              // If not consumable
              RNIap.acknowledgePurchaseAndroid(purchase.purchaseToken);
            }
          } else {
            // Retry / conclude the purchase is fraudulent, etc...
          }
        });
      }
    });

    this.purchaseErrorSubscription = purchaseErrorListener((error: PurchaseError) => {
      console.warn('purchaseErrorListener', error);
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.purchaseUpdateSubscription) {
      this.purchaseUpdateSubscription.remove();
      this.purchaseUpdateSubscription = null;
    }
    if (this.purchaseErrorSubscription) {
      this.purchaseErrorSubscription.remove();
      this.purchaseErrorSubscription = null;
    }
  }
}
```

Here i am not sure what is 'yourAPI.deliverOrDownloadFancyInAppPurchase'?
Please help, anyone who can know about 'yourAPI'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually your api :) It is mean when a product is purchased with native in-app purchase, you want to make call to your api (backend). Four example in a game, you can sell a starter package for gamers with in-app purchase, firstly user will pay a value to google play or app store for this starter package. And you should know if this action finished as succesfully and you should give this starter kit to user. For this, you should make a call inside of this listener like `backendApi.sold(purchase.transactionReceipt).then((result) => {});`